# Is there a way to conditionally serialize C# list objects based on a property?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, json-serialization

I have an MVC Model that generates JSON files, based off of user inputs, that are used as part of an automated workflow. The issue that I am having is figuring out how to change the order in which a list of objects are serialized based off of a specific property value.

Here is a simplified look at my model:

```
public class Ticket
{
    public string TicketNumber { get; set; }
    public string TicketName { get; set; }
    public string ApplicationName { get; set; }
    public IList<Jams> JamsList { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public Ticket ChangeTicket { get; set; }
}

public class JamsDestination
{
    public string Dev { get; set; }
    public string QA { get; set; }
    public string Prod { get; set; }
}

public class Jams
{
    public string TFSLocation { get; set; }       
    public string FileName { get; set; }
    public string JamsType { get; set; }
    public JamsDestination JamsLocation { get; set; }
}
```

(I am using Newtonsoft.Json and the SerializeObject() function in the post section of my controller)

JamsType is a drop down list populated from a sql table (Variable, Job, Trigger, and Box). What I am trying to do is ensure that any Jams change (in the list: JamsList) is serialized in an order that **ensures that all Jams changes of JamsType = Box are serialized last**, in order to ensure that it will run properly as a part of our automated workflow. **Is there any way to accomplish this** without setting up some form of Javascript function in the view to reorder them before they are indexed? (My view is a dynamic table setup so it is not guaranteed that there even will be any Jams changes each time, let alone how many are associated with a ticket).

Comment: You can use linq for ordering your list before passing it.  `JamsList.OrderBy(t=> t.JamsType != Box)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized that I just needed to add Linq logic into my controller PRIOR to serializing the JSON file by doing the following:

```
ticket.JamsList = ticket.JamsList.OrderBy(jams => jams.JamsType == "Box").ToList();
```

All this actually does is just reorder the list of Jams changes to meet my conditions before it gets serialized, rather than changing the order it serializes the list (how I thought it needed to be performed).